# Adding AES encryption to VC++ application

Tags: visual-c++, encryption, mfc, aes

I created a GUI application in VC++ and now I wanted to do a AES128 encryption to the data, I am writting to it.

Can anyone please let me know how can I do that in VC++.

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you do research and pick an off the shelf encryption solution if this data is at all sensitive as doing encryption correctly is hard.

Answer (score 8):

Microsoft provides the **CryptoAPI**, which is built-in to Windows.

The starting point for the documentation is here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380255(v=VS.85).aspx

A general usage overview:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms867086.aspx

Sample programs written in C:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382016(v=VS.85).aspx

And here is a list of supported algorithms, including AES128:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb931357(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using http://www.openssl.org/ there's a guide for using it with vc++ @ http://www.devside.net/guides/windows/openssl

--edit

You should use the latest version from openssl's site instead of the old version in that guide, everything else in the guide applies.